# Notation for transpose of a matrix row

Tags: matrices, notation, transpose

Given a matrix $\mathbf{X}$, I use $\mathbf{x}_{i}^{T}$ and $\mathbf{x}_{i}$ to denote the $i$-th row and $i$-th column of matrix $\mathbf{X}$ respectively. Now, suppose I want to denote the transpose of the $i$-th matrix row $\mathbf{x}_{i}^{T}$, then what notation will be suitable here?

I know we can represent rows and columns using $x_{i*}$ and $x_{*j}$ respectively. But are there any alternatives?

Comment: Go for $r_{i}$ to denote $i^{th}$ row and $c_{i}$ to denote $i^{th}$ column making it easier for you to define transpose?

Comment: Thank you for you comment. The problem is that I am dealing with multiple matrices that I denote with uppercase bold face alphabets. So, to refer to their rows and columns I was looking to use lowercase bold face of the same alphabet.